# Is S a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Let S be the set of real numbers in the form (x,y). With these operations defined,

$(x,y)+(a,b)=(x, y+b)$

$\alpha(x,y)=(\alpha x,\alpha y)$

is S a vector space?

Well my answer is it can't because $(x,y)+(a,b) \neq (x+a,y+b)$, but I guess it is incomplete...
Thoughts?

Comment: $(x,y)+(1,0)=(x,y)=(x,y)+(2,0)$ but $(1,0) \neq (2,0)$.

Comment: How many neutral elements for the sum must a verctor space have? How many have $S$?

Answer (score 1):

A vector space must verify that it's sum operator is commutative for all elements. You can easily see that in your case
$$(x,y)+(a,b)=(x, y+b) \neq (a,b+y)=(a,b)+(x,y) \text{ , for } a\neq x$$
Since $(x,y+b)\neq(a,b+y)$ in general, then your $(S,+,\cdot)$ is not a vector space.

You can also notice that your $(S,+,\cdot)$ has an infinite number of neutral elements, because
$$(x,y)+(\lambda,0)=(x,y) \phantom{a} , \phantom{a} \forall \lambda \in \mathbb{R},$$
and vector spaces verify that they must have a unique neutral element. Then we got another prove that $(S,+,\cdot)$ is not a vector space.

Comment: Ok I got it, but my main doubt is if saying (x,y)+(a,b)≠(x+a,y+b) I make any sense or am I proving anything

Comment: @arpg That statement is not enough for proving that it's not a vector space, since there may be vector spaces which sum does not verify that property and still are vector spaces.

Comment: Could you give an example to illustrate?

Comment: @arpg I'm not sure now if what I stated that it may not verify it is true (talking about vector spaces in $\mathbb{R}^2$). I'll think a bit more and will tell you what I found.